# Facebook Like Button Grabbing Content From Wrong Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

On my site, I've implemented some facebook like buttons on the articles which works for all of them but one. If you 'like' an article, such as [this one](http://www.theslam.co.uk/article/ranticles/L.A.-Noire-The-Unrewarding-Story/) then it works fine and grabs the right image, right content and puts them on my facebook profile. However, when I 'like' [this one](http://www.theslam.co.uk/article/retrospectacles/Supernatural-Where-did-it-all-go-wrong/) it grabs the content and the url of the home page, made worse by the carousel on the homepage which means that it gets content from that and not even the intro text there.

This has been driving me crazy. Please help me.

Comment: Did you use any of the [automatic code generators](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?  Just gathering more information...

Comment: No, none. I'm nit trying to accomplish anything too outlandish, just to get the like button to put a bit of text and a link to the current page on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Next time this happens, use the [Facebook Linter tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to debug it and clear any info Facebook has cached.  I did this for your URL and it should be working now.

Comment: Yup, this seems to have solved the issue. Thing is, I was trying that over and over again. Maybe facebook takes a little while to clear it's caches or something. Either way, thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. It's reverted to grabbing the content from the homepage again. Running the Linter has no effect.